# rake failure ruby 2.7.0 "undefined method extend_object for class Singleton

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm attempting to install Ruby on Rails version 5.0.0 using Ruby 2.7.0 on Ubuntu. Executing any rake command (eg, "rake --tasks") results in a large number of messages about already initialized constants (Etc::VERSION, Etc::SC_AIO_LISTIO_MAX, etc.) followed by

```
rake aborted! 
NameError: undefined method `extend_object' for class `Singleton'
Did you mean?  extended
```

The answer to [Error when running rake db:create: undefined method `extend_object' for class `Singleton'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66231072/error-when-running-rake-dbcreate-undefined-method-extend-object-for-class-s) suggests removing Gemfile.lock and re-executing bundle install, but this had no effect for me. Are there other fixes?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today, updating ruby to 3.0.0 seems to solve this problem. Ubuntu for some reason downloads version 2.7.0, I used this article to help me install ruby 3.0.0

https://linoxide.com/how-to-install-ruby-on-ubuntu-20-04/

You will obviously also need to change the version in Gemfile and ruby-version file.

Comment: Thanks. The Rails system I am maintaining was written for older versions and I am wary of moving to Ruby 3.0 until other issues are resolved. I suppose this is impetus to try to get those things done. But it seems strange that Rails will run otherwise with what is an apparent version mismatch. I don’t recall other such undocumented version mismatches between Ruby and Rails.